# Swap classes between div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swap

I have 2 main div's. Group1 and group2. Those group divs contain other 2 (or more) div each. All the div's inside the group's have a class of `.grp_item`. Now grp_item is `display:none` and only one div in each group has a class .sel which is `display:block` .

How can I swap the class `.sel` between the groups ? Div's inside the groups are the same between them.

Here is the structure:

```
<div id="group1">
    <div class="grp_item">
        <div>
        Div First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grp_item sel">
        <div>
        Div second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div><button id="swap">SWAP</button></div>

<div id="group2">
    <div class="grp_item sel">
        <div>
        Div First
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grp_item">
        <div>
        Div Two
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So for this example, when swap button pressed, set `.sel` in group one to the first Div and in group2 set `.sel` to Div Two.

Here is the fiddle of the structure: http://jsfiddle.net/d6TFh/

Note that I can't add any more classes in the inner div's so I would imagine I should be first setting the classes to each and then removing them.

Is this possible using `.contain()` or any other way?

Comment: Hmmm... I've never heard of `$(element).on("click", function() { });` in jQuery... I think it is `$(element).click(function() { });` or `$(element).trigger("click", function() { });`

Comment: @Nathan: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker oh ok. I searched google but it doesn't say anything about `.on()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your conversation with Ayman Safadi I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var a = $('#anything .sel').attr('id')
var b = $('#something .sel').attr('id')

$('#anything .sel').removeClass('sel')
$('#anything').find('#' + b).addClass('sel');

$('#something .sel').removeClass('sel')
$('#something').find('#' + a).addClass('sel');
```

And the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6TFh/10/

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/d6TFh/3/

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $('div[id^="group"] > div').toggleClass('sel')
});
```

Comment: Wow fantastic. Never thought of this. It seems to be restricted on 'group(NO)' though.

Comment: What could I do if the group1 and group2 were grp and group accordingly ? E.g group1 = grp, group2 = group

Comment: Yes it is, but I was just following your sample code.  Replace the DIV selector for whatever works best for you.  If you'd like to share some more markup, I'd be happy to help narrow it down for you.

Comment: I've narrowed things down in my actual page and deleted the inner empty divs and placed the class on the actual div with ID. Also the same id's in grp1 are in grp2. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6TFh/7/ Can you give me a sample on this one as I would imagine it would be alot easier. Thanks much

Comment: hm this works but it doesn't in my actual example since it comes down from many divs and not as the example exactly.